# ipython R : X11 module cannot be loaded

Tags: r, ipython, rpy2, conda

Initially I had a rpy2 related issue but after solving that now I am getting following error when I use R within ipython cell:

```
    %%R
    plot(7)
    Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
    In addition: Warning message:
    In png("/tmp/tmplXba8T/Rplots%03d.png", ) : failed to load cairo DLL
    Error in (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  : 
      X11 module cannot be loaded
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In png("/tmp/tmp_avqKe/Rplots%03d.png", ) : failed to load cairo DLL
    2: In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
      unable to load shared object '/../R/3.0.2/precise-x86_64/lib/R/modules//R_X11.so':
      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: cairo_ft_font_options_substitute
    Error in (function (display = "",width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  : 
  X11 module cannot be loaded
```

I am using [conda](https://store.continuum.io/) I thought using conda should be better than setting up via virtualenv but looks like this is really a pain.

Comment: Does doing a plot in plain R and saving to PNG work?

Comment: Yes I manage to do the same command in r (without using studio) and plot did work

Comment: Then it's probably an issue with rpy2. I've added the appropriate tag. The mailing list is [here](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/rpy-list) if you don't get an answer on SO.

Comment: rpy2 was not available in conda version so i did easy_install and install rpy2